# How to set up gtkmm on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gtkmm

I want to get into developing GUI applications with GTK+. Following some instructions, I downloaded the gtkmm package and its dependencies. However, when I try to compile the GTK+ application, g++ throws me this error: `g++: error: pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs: No such file or directory` I believe it does this because it can't link the libraries, but how do I fix this?

Comment: I feel a little stupid now. Here is how I compiled my application: `g++ main.cpp -o main 'pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs'`. This isn't the proper way to do it. Here's why: In bash, anything surrounded in quotes, be they single or double, is treated as a file or directory. You have to put `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` in backticks instead of quotes. It is then treated as executable code, instead of a file directory. I guess I should go to bed.:P

Comment: You can try anjuta :)

Comment: You can post the answer to your own post and accept the answer.